# Index of an element in a numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Given a matrix like the following:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],
          [3,4,5],
          [4,5,6]])
```

How can I pinpoint the index of an element of interest. For example, assume I would like to find the index of `2` in the first row of the `np.array`, like so:
`A[0,:].index(2)`, but clearly this does not work because `A[0,:]` is not a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the array to the value `2`, and then use [`where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

For example, to find the location of `2` in the first row of `A`:

```
In [179]: np.where(A[0, :] == 2)[0]
Out[179]: array([1])

In [180]: j = np.where(A[0, :] == 2)[0]

In [181]: A[0, j]
Out[181]: array([2])
```

`where` also works with higher-dimensional arrays.  For example, to find `2` in the full array `A`:

```
In [182]: i, j = np.where(A == 2)

In [183]: A[i,j]
Out[183]: array([2])
```